# How to better convert a curl to ansible uri

Tags: curl, ansible

Convert a curl command to uri

```
curl -kG "https://{{inventory_hostname}}/api/?type=export&category=configuration&key=<key>"
```

I am using this playbook:

```
tasks:
    - name: Backup Palo
      uri:
         validate_certs: no
         url: https://{{inventory_hostname}}/api/?type=config&action=show&key={{LUFRPT1YOXlKeWZ1SWc4TFliTGpldEJQVVRYSEpZak09eitKQUlDeGtaTjZ5d09Yb2EvVml0ZmFEbENZUm9qcUJCbWttSFJQS3BMYz0= }}
         return_content: yes
         method: PUT
      register: result

    - copy:
        content: "{{ result['content'] }}"
        dest: backup/{{ansible_network_os}}/{{inventory_hostname}}-{{date}}.cfg
```

However, I always get the following error:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "connection": "close", "content": "<html>\r\n<head><title>411 Length Required</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center><h1>411 Length Required</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center></center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n", "content_length": "169", "content_type": "text/html", "date": "Tue, 06 Aug 2019 20:46:15 GMT", "elapsed": 0, "msg": "Status code was 411 and not [200]: HTTP Error 411: Length Required", "redirected": false, "status": 411,
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues here that I can see:

1. You should be using the HTTP GET method (not PUT)
2. You do not need to enclose the key in braces (unless you store it in a variable)
3. I think the query string is incorrect. It doesn't match your example curl command, nor the Palo Alto documentation (but I admit I know nothing about Palo Alto devices)

Try:

```
    - name: Backup Palo
      uri:
         validate_certs: no
         url: https://{{inventory_hostname}}/api/?type=export&category=configuration&key=LUFRPT1YOXlKeWZ1SWc4TFliTGpldEJQVVRYSEpZak09eitKQUlDeGtaTjZ5d09Yb2EvVml0ZmFEbENZUm9qcUJCbWttSFJQS3BMYz0=
         return_content: yes
         method: GET
      register: result
```